# RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379. при заданном другом хосте. Как исправить?

Tags: spring, docker, jenkins, java-8, redis

Есть Spring boot приложение, использующее Redis.
Конфигурация redis:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceConfiguration = RedisConfiguration.class)
public class RedisConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {

    @Value("${timestamp}")
    public long timeStamp;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("redis");

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasSettingsFor(Class<?> type) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyspaceSettings getKeyspaceSettings(Class<?> type) {
        KeyspaceSettings keyspaceSettings = new KeyspaceSettings(type, "my-keyspace");
        keyspaceSettings.setTimeToLive(timeStamp);
        return keyspaceSettings;
    }
}
```

зависимости для redis:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Есть тест:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataRedisTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private User user;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        user = new User("user", "password");
    }

    @Test
    public void createUserTest(){
        AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat(userRepository.save(user)).isEqualTo(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenFindByName_thenReturnUser() {
        userRepository.save(user);
        User found = userRepository.findById(user.getName()).get();
        AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat(found).isEqualTo(user);
    }
```

И здесь начинается самое веселое.

1) Если приложение собираю и запускаю локально, при указанном хосте `'localhost'` все ок, ошибок нету. При хосте с именем `'redis'` получаю `java.net.UnknownHostException: redis`. Значит хост указывается и все исправно.

2) Второй вариант, приложение собирается в Docker контейнете, и привязано к Jenkins. Также поднят другой контейнер с Redis. Связь между контейнерами налажена и проверена (задан хост с именем `'redis'`). 
 Запускаю тест и получаю:

```
 RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; `nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379`
```

Не пойму где искать ошибку. С чем это может быть связано? И откуда взялся `localhost:6379`?

Дополнительно, Jenkinsfile конфигурация:

```
node {
    def signingBot
    def redisContainer

    stage('Clone repository') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('Prepare') {
        redisContainer = docker.image('redis:4.0.7-alpine')
        signingBot = docker.build("signing-bot")
    }

    stage('build') {
        redisContainer.withRun() { c ->
            sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
            signingBot.inside("--link ${c.id}:redis") {
//                sleep 5
                sh 'cat /etc/hosts'
                stage('test') {
                    sh 'mvn test'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Недавно столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой: локально все работало просто замечательно, а в кластере опеншифта сыпало ошибками с попытками подключиться к локалхосту, хотя все переменные окружения были заданы верно.

Проблема оказалась в том, что Spring Boot автоматически создает конфигурации с дефолтными хостом и портом для редиса (`localhost:6379`).

Решил проблему такими строками в `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
```